# Is there any technique available to pass arbitrary text to JavaScript via CSS rules?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any CSS properties that make good candidates to overload with metadata that could be used by JavaScript to create custom enhancements? or is there some other technique/hack which could be used to arbitrary strings from CSS to JavaScript?

The specific use case is this:

- User submitted CSS is used to theme static markup.
- A layer of JavaScript will optionally enable enable enhanced embedded content (for example a graph or other visualization) and the user should be able to style this markup in various fashions.
- Examples: selecting specific data points to be incorporated, choosing a type of chart line/bar that will be rendered, creating a visualization in a certain shape.

This will need to work in all modern browsers and IE9 and above. 
*I'd also like to avoid to avoid the added complexity of introducing LESS if possible*

Comment: How is the visualisation done? Can't you write CSS for that embedded content?

Comment: Some of it is SVG. One example is I want to give the user (CSS themer) the ability to choose a shape type (circle, square, star) that will be generated by my JS, but in SVG these are entirely different base types (rect, circle, polygon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use comments in the css file

```
/* define myUserData: "myUserValue" */
```

Then parse the css file using an ajax call to the file.

something like this

```
jQuery.get("test.css", null, function(data) {
    var comments = data.match(/\/\* define.*\*\//g);
    for each (var c in comments) 
        alert(c);
});
```

It's an extra request, but as css files are usually cached locally (depending on server and client settings) it shouldn't be an expensive request for the majority of users.

Comment: This does seem cleaner, and less "hacky" then what I had in mind, supplementing the css ruleset rather than overloading it. I could even create my own vendor prefix. -chris-transform: ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use a selector that will never apply
Sounds like something like this may be more useful for your use case.

You do however need to loop through the cssRules object for each stylesheet.

If you know the href of your stylesheet or you can match it via regex, then you can just parse that stylesheet.

```
/* css */
.this-is-config.variableName
{ 
      /* quotes works and is valid css */
      quotes:"circle";
      /* content works, but should only be for pseudo elements */
      content: "hey-hey";
      /* Some other rules will not work */
      color: "rouge";
}
```

To get value

```
/* js */
function getConfig(variableName) {
    // search backwards because the last match is more likely the right one
    for (var s= document.styleSheets.length - 1; s >= 0; s--) {

        // if you know the href of the stylesheet you can continue here
        /*
        if (isNotTheRightStylesheet(document.styleSheets[s].href) ) {
          continue;
        }
        */

        // get all the rules in this stylesheet
        var cssRules = document.styleSheets[s].cssRules ||
                document.styleSheets[s].rules || []; // IE support            

        // find matching selector
        for (var c=0; c < cssRules.length; c++) {
            if (cssRules[c].selectorText === '.this-is-config.' + variableName) 
                return cssRules[c].style['quotes'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var value = getConfig('variableName');
```

Experiment here with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chim/2afAt/1/)

Comment: Nice fiddle. And love the use of the quotes property (can't believe there's a CSS2 property I've never heard of)

Comment: Yeah, scratched my head trying to think of the best candidate. I still thing approach one is slightly cleaner (with the comments)